# Writing data to Firebase using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to iOS developing and trying to save a users name, dob and address to firebase. The user can currently successfully sign up and log in. Can someone please advise?

I am unsure also if my JSON tree is structured correctly

Also, how can I let firebase know to update the current users details??

Thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class BabysitterProfileViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var dobTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var addressTextField: UITextField!


    // create the reference here
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }


    @IBAction func updateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        ref = Database.database().reference()


     self.ref.child("Babysitter/\(Babysitter.uid)/Name").setValue(nameTextField)

    }

}
```

Here is my JSON tree

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this:

```
self.ref.child("Babysitter").child(Babysitter.uid).updateChildValues(["Name": nameTextField.text])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The following error occurs, "Use of unresolved identifier 'Babysitter'" how can I fix this please?

Comment: You need the UID of the babysitter you're trying to update the values for. I need more details to help.

Comment: How can I find the uid?

Comment: Look at my answer again

Comment: Accept the answer if it's working for you. And if you got other questions. Let me know!

Comment: same error appearing. Have created the same JSON tree as you. Not sure what to else to do...

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HN7usMROt8